# How do you add additional scoping to Devise user_signed_in? helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I have authentication that needs to be independent across:

subdomain1.domain.com
subdomain2.domain.com
etc.

Right now with the devise `user_signed_in?` helper - if someone authenticates on subdomain1, it is working on subdomain2.  I would like to add a tenant_id scope to prevent this from happening.

I have been able to do this on login authentication in my model using:

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
      where(:email => warden_conditions[:email], :tenant_id => warden_conditions[:tenant_id]).first
end
```

But I am not clear on how to do this on the logged in check.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order do to do this you need to narrow the scope of the authentication to just the subdomain.

Here is a [Docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Scope-login-to-subdomain) page on how to accomplish this. I'll add it here for reference:

**Overview**

1. Modify the Devise-generated migration to remove the index on email uniqueness constraint
2. Change login keys to include `:subdomain`
3. Override Devise hook method `find_for_authentication`

**Modify migration**

First, you must remove the email index uniqueness constraint. Because we'll be turning this into a scoped query, we will scope the new index to subdomain. If this is a brand new Devise model, you can open the Devise migration and change the following:

```
# db/migrate/XXX_devise_create_users.rb
def change
  # Remove this line
  add_index :users, :email, :unique => true

  # Replace with
  add_index :users, [:email, :subdomain], :unique => true
end
```

If this is an existing project, you'll need to create a new migration removing the old index and adding a new one:

```
rails g migration reindex_users_by_email_and_subdomain


# db/migrate/XXX_reindex_users_by_email_and_subdomain.rb
def change
  remove_index :users, :email
  add_index :users, [:email, :subdomain], :unique => true
end
```

**Change login keys**

In your Devise model, add `:subdomain` to `:request_keys`. By default `:request_keys` is set to `[]`.

```
   # app/models/user.rb
class User
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, request_keys: [:subdomain]
end
```

If you have multiple Devise models and you would like all of them to have the same :request_keys configuration, you can set that globally in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.request_keys = [:subdomain] # default value = []
```

If additionally you want to still be able to log in using a URL without a subdomain, `:request_keys` can also take a hash with booleans indicating if the key is required or not.

```
config.request_keys = { subdomain: false }
```

**Check that you do not have `:validatable` in the devise call on the Model**

If you do, :validatable will prevent more than one record having the same email, even in different subdomains. If you want to keep some of the validations, you can copy the ones you want from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb

**Override Devise auth finder hook**

For Authenticatable, Devise uses the hook method Model.find_for_authentication. Override it to include your additional query parameters:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_for_authentication(warden_conditions)
    where(:email => warden_conditions[:email], :subdomain => warden_conditions[:subdomain]).first
  end
end
```

Congrats, User login is now scoped to subdomain!